# ASP.Net MVC 4 Bundles - Using variables in path names

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to generate a dynamic css path - similar to the path below, where "VARIABLE" changes based on runtime values - using the bundling component of MVC4.

Is there a way to do this?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/brand/VARIABLE/global/global.css">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this is what you are looking for? The code below simply gets the value of the `theme` configuration setting:

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
{
  bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("/~Content/css").
    Include(String.Format("~/Content/{0}/site.css",
    ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("theme"))));

}
```

In your view, just call `Styles.Render`:

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css");
```

If you need to use other values than configuration settings, I guess you will need a static method that returns the corresponding value.